# IntelliJ not recognize scala imports

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Everyday when i turn on my laptop i need to organize the imports of my project, i mean, IntelliJ not recognize some imports of scala's playframework and i need to do all the time the next steps

1. sbt clean
2. close IDE
3. delete .idea folder
4. import scala SDK Module
5. file/ invalidate cache and Restart
   finally 3 o more times cleaning the project this works ok until i turn off my laptop and start again the next day

[this is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pancc.png)
and this is my 
[Build.sbt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAgR0.jpg)
and this is [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHf5s.jpg),
i actually works with 
**IntelliJ 2018.3.2
sbt 1.2.7
scala 2.12.8**

**IMPORTANT:**
my app was working ok without all the imports they aren't necessary only that you can see in the picture

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to prefix `_root_` to all the Scala core packages? Like for example...

```
import _root_.scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import _root_.scala.concurrent.Future
```